Use std::ranges::to to collect std::ranges::lazy_split_view into std::vector
In Rust, I can write (Rust Playground):
let vec = "Hello-+-Rust-+-!".split("-+-").collect::<Vec<_>>();
println!("{:?}", vec); // ["Hello", "Rust", "!"]

And I'd like to do the same in C++23.
I wrote (Compiler Explorer):
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <print>

int main()
{
    auto vec = "Hello-+-C++-+-23-+-!" 
        | std::ranges::views::lazy_split(std::string_view("-+-"))
        | std::ranges::to<std::vector<std::string_view>>();

    std::println("{}", vec);
}

But clang reported 2 errors:
In file included from <source>:1:
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/clang-trunk-20240518/bin/../include/c++/v1/ranges:416:
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-trunk-20240518/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ranges/to.h:134:18: error: no matching function for call to 'to'
  134 |           return ranges::to<range_value_t<_Container>>(std::forward<decltype(__elem)>(__elem));
      |                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
...
/opt/compiler-explorer/clang-trunk-20240518/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ranges/to.h:133:27: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ref_view<lazy_split_view<ref_view<const char[21]>, string_view>>' (aka 'ref_view<std::ranges::lazy_split_view<std::ranges::ref_view<const char[21]>, std::string_view>>') and '__range_adaptor_closure_t<__bind_back_t<__fn, tuple<(lambda at /opt/compiler-explorer/clang-trunk-20240518/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ranges/to.h:133:46)>>>' (aka 'std::ranges::__range_adaptor_closure_t<std::__bind_back_t<std::ranges::views::__transform::__fn, std::tuple<(lambda at /opt/compiler-explorer/clang-trunk-20240518/bin/../include/c++/v1/__ranges/to.h:133:46)>>>'))
  133 |         ref_view(__range) | views::transform([](auto&& __elem) {
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  134 |           return ranges::to<range_value_t<_Container>>(std::forward<decltype(__elem)>(__elem));
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  135 |         }),
      |         ~~
...
2 errors generated.
ASM generation compiler returned: 1

How could I understand where it went wrong?

Ah yes, the helpful and human readable error messages concepts brought to us.

The value type of lazy_split is at most a forward range, you can't convert that into a string_view which requires contiguous. std::ranges::to<std::vector<std::string>> works though.

@T.C. The underlying data of lazy_split's result isn't contiguous (as a whole), but I suppose the underlying data of each fragment is contiguous?

For that usage, std::views::split is a better option. Also using namespace std::literals; is an exception against general rule, that makes life a lot  easier: "-+-"sv is shorter and more readable.

@Red.Wave I tried replacing lazy_split with split, but it didn't help.

views::lazy_split is lazy, which means that splitting subranges only satisfy forward_range at most, you should use views::split
auto vec = "Hello-+-C++-+-23-+-!" 
    | std::ranges::views::split(std::string_view("-+-"))
    | std::views::transform([](auto r) { return std::string_view{r}; })
    | std::ranges::to<std::vector>();

std::println("{}", vec);

Demo

Could you explain why we need the std::views::transform step, what's the item type of the iterator without this transform?

And I'd like to know how to get those information from online documents. For example, I couldn't find out what the item type of a lazy_split_view is if V is a std::string (which it isn't in the original demo) and Pattern is a std::string_view from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/lazy_split_view .

The splitting subranges by views::split are not of string_view type (but subrange), so views::transform converts these subranges into string_view.

So std::ranges::views::split returns an iterator over ranges::subrange<ranges::iterator_t<V>>s which are roughly equivalent to Rust slices that could be cheaply turned into std::string_views (when V is contiguous), while std::ranges::views::lazy_split returns an iterator over iterators that doesn't satisfy the above trait, so it can only be reconstucted into newly allocated std::strings, am I getting these right?

How I wish cppreference could be as user friendly as Rust std doc. Currently a lot of "A models this when B models that" are all stuffed together without examples which makes the details really easily overlooked. And there's also a huge missing "when should you use which since they look similar" guide.

std::views is an aliase for std::ranges::views. I guess this is just a copy+paste residue. The problem seems to be that string_view has an explicit constructor for generic ranges(#6); so the verbose transform is essential for conversion.

@SunshineLi Your guess is correct.
